# why PHP decoding url '+' character as space?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my javascript jquery ajax function to send data. Here i append my data with url to send it to server.

```
 url = "/login/auth/";
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: url+encodeURIComponent("a+b+2"),
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (data.login === false)
                {
                    alert("Invalid Password");
                } else {
                    $('.login').hide();
                    $("body").append(data.html);
                }

            }
        });
```

In PHP

```
 if (isset($_GET['r']))
 {
        echo 'r='.$_GET['r'];
        return explode('/',rtrim($_GET['r'], '/'));
    }
```

PHP decoding it as  login/auth/a b 2

Comment: url via ajax request is login/auth/%7B%22pwd%22%3A%22a%2Bb%2B2%22%7D

Comment: Where is `?r=` in your URL?

Comment: `login/auth/%7B%22pwd%22%3A%22a%2Bb%2B2%22%7D` should not result in `login/auth/a b 2`, even with double decoding. Are you sure you test the right url and you're not getting a page from cache?

Comment: ?r= is in .htaccess file in server @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing apache rewrite rule flag to [NE,B,L,QSA] solved the problem.
Here B(Back Reference) flag is set to avoid decoding of the url component.

Answer (score 1):

It's because a `+` symbol in a url means a space. It's basically a shorter (and more readable) version of `%20`.

To send a `+` encode it as you would with any other special character. An encoded `+` is `%2B`. But actually, encodeURIComponent should do that already. Did you maybe decode the url twice in PHP?

Comment: then how do i send + symbol as data to server

Comment: See edited answer, but since you already use `encodeURIComponent`, I'm not sure what could be the problem. Note though, that PHP will automatically decode the url once, so you don't need `url_decode` in PHP to decode (parts of) your URL yourself. If you need debugging help with the PHP part, please add that code to the question too.

Comment: Weird issue. I've tried your code in a small script on my localhost WAMP. With `?r=a+b+c` it echoes `a b c`, but with `?r=a%2Bb%2Bc` it echoes `a+b+c`, like it should. Maybe it's some configuration or a bug, but I can't find any reference of it, and I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I suspect the extra decode may be related to the Apache rewrite rule.